# Linux Libertine: Change Numeral Set

Tags: fonts, luatex, oldstylenums, libertine

I am using the Linux Libertine font for my document. The font provides different [numeral sets](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=87&L=1#c477), "normal" numbers which are all the same height, and medieval/minuscle numbers with varying height.

[image]

By default, LaTeX uses the normal numbers but I prefer the look of the medieval numbers.

How can I tell LaTeX which numeral set to use?

P.S.: I am using LuaLaTeX

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX you can specifiy font features with the [`fontspec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package.

The `Numbers`/`RawFeature` features are

- `Lining` and `Uppercase`/`lnum`: normal/majuscule figures
- `OldStyle` and `Lowercase`/`onum`: medieval/minuscule figures
- `Proportional`/`pnum`
- `Monospaced`/`tnum` (`t` stands for tabular)
- `SlashedZero`/`zero`: gives slashed 0

You can activate these features with either

```
\addfontfeatures{Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}}
```

or

```
\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+onum;+pnum}
```

If you use the [`libertineotf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertineotf) package (which also provides shortcuts to change these settings in-document, cf the package manual), you can give these arguments directly as package options:

```
\usepackage[
    libertine={Ligatures=TeX,RawFeature=+onum;+pnum},
     biolinum={Ligatures=TeX,RawFeature=+onum;+pnum},
         mono={Scale=MatchLowercase,RawFeature=+zero}]
    {libertineotf}
```

If you don't you can still set the options directly when specifying the fonts:

```
\setmainfont[RawFeature=+onum;+pnum]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[RawFeature=+onum;+pnum]{Linux Biolinum O}
```

---

Here is an exemplary code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\def\numbers{0123456789}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lrrr}
        \textbf{Normal Zero} &                                              Monospaced &                                              Proportional &  \\
        Lining               &   \addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}}\numbers &  \addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining,Proportional}} \numbers &  \\
        OldStyle             & \addfontfeatures{Numbers={OldStyle,Monospaced}}\numbers & \addfontfeatures{Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}}\numbers &  \\
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{1ex}
    \addfontfeatures{Numbers=SlashedZero}
    \begin{tabular}{lrrr}
        \textbf{Slashed Zero} &                                              Monospaced &                                              Proportional &  \\
        Lining                &   \addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}}\numbers &  \addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining,Proportional}} \numbers &  \\
        OldStyle              & \addfontfeatures{Numbers={OldStyle,Monospaced}}\numbers & \addfontfeatures{Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}}\numbers &  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use `Numbers=OldStyle`:

```
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle}]{Linux Libertine O}
```

From `fontspec`'s doc, table 4:

```
 Feature         Option             Tag

 Numbers =      Uppercase/Lining     lnum
                Lowercase/OldStyle   onum
                Proportional         pnum
                Monospaced           tnum
                SlashedZero          zero
                Arabic               anum
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[libertine={Ligatures=TeX,RawFeature=+onum}]{libertineotf}
\begin{document}

0123456789

\end{document}
```

or also for the sans serif Biolinum

```
\usepackage[libertine={Ligatures=TeX,RawFeature=+onum},
            biolinum={Ligatures=TeX,RawFeature=+onum}]{libertineotf}
```